# How to connect to Vitess database with JDBC connector

Tags: jdbc, vitess

I'm trying to connect to Vitess database.
To my best knowledge I have to use dedicated JDBC connector (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vitess/vitess-jdbc) for the Vitess. I have tried to connect like this:

```
#1 jdbc:vitess://user:password@hostname:port/
#2 jdbc:vitess://user:password@hostname:port/my_schema
#3 jdbc:vitess://user:password@hostname:port/my_schema#replica
#4 jdbc:vitess://user:password@hostname:port/keyspace/my_schema
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
Driver class 'io.vitess.proto.Query$ExecuteOptions$IncludedFields' not found.
```

I have found information regarding `IncludedFields` in https://vitess.io/zh/docs/reference/vitess-api/
I also tried to put this value into database url (`?included_fields=all` or `?included_fields=2`), but apparently there is no effect at all.

Is there any way to connect to Vitess through JDBC connector?

Answer (score 0):

Vitess can be used with mysql driver with connection string "jdbc:mysql://:

The Vitess JDBC driver uses grpc protocol, currently it is not managed.

For now, we suggest to use mysql java connector.